# I need to make a search in sqlite and deploy the same data compairing with a new parameter

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database with the name of various users and a personal code (RFC).
I need to make a search in both tables(name and RFC), introducing a new parameter, comparing and deploying a list with the same name or the same code (RFC).

But my program only deploys the first record with the same name or code (RFC).
If a have multiple users with the same name I need to deploy all users, not only the first one found.

```
listUser=new ArrayList<>();

 private void consultSQL() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] parameter={campoId.getText().toString() , campoId.getText().toString() };
    User user=null;

    try {
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT "
                +Utilities.TABLE_ID+","
                +Utiliiess.TABLE_NAME+","
                +Utilities.TABLE_NUMBER+ ","
                +Utilities.TABLE_RFC+ ","
                +Utilities.TABLE_PASSWORD+
                " FROM "+Utilidades.TABLE_USER+" WHERE "+Utilities.TABLE_NAME+ " = ? OR " +Utilities.TABLE_RFC+" = ? ",parameter);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
            user = new User();
            user.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            user.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            user.setNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            user.setRFC(cursor.getString(3));
            user.setPassword(cursor.getString(4));

            listUser.add(user);



    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No coincidence",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: You’re supposed to loop over a cursor.

Answer (score 2):

You move to the first element of cursor with

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

So you get the first record. Cursor has all the records you want but you do not iterate over cursor to get them. To iterate over cursor use

```
 User = new User();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            user.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            user.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            user.setNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            user.setRFC(cursor.getString(3));
            user.setPassword(cursor.getString(4));

            listUser.add(user);
    }
```